# Powershell - Find string then copy string right next to it

Tags: string, powershell, search, copy

need help generating a powershell script that finds a string from a text file - then copies the string **next to it**. Planning to use this for extracting data from generic forms.

For instance, here's a line from the wall of text:

> Name : Jill Valentine

Hoping to use the 'Name' string to extract the 'Jill Valentine' string then store it in a variable. Something like for checking:

`$name = $_.contains("Name:")`

I will be using Get-content to read from a text file. Any ideas?

Comment: how exactly do you want to extract the string that comes next to the one, you are looking for? For example, what approach is used in your example to get 'Jill Valentine'? Is it the string that comes after 'Name: ' till the end of the line, or something else?

Comment: Until the end of line - sorry should have been more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use regex, for example if you want anything that follow `Name :`

```
(get-content c:\temp\your_file_with_names.txt)  | % { 
    if ($_ -match "name : (.*)") { 
        $name = $matches[1]
        echo $name
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying it now!

Answer (score 1):

Generic solution will look like that

```
function Get-FormDataById ($path, $id){
      $dataRegex = "^$id(.+)$"
      Get-Content $path  | % { 
        if ($_ -match $dataRegex ) { 
           $matches[1]
        }
      }
}
```

Usage

```
Get-FormDataById -path "C:\test.txt" -id "name: " //returns 'John Smith'
Get-FormDataById -path "C:\test.txt" -id "age: "  //returns 28
```

Content of `C:\test.txt`

```
name: John Smith
age: 28
```

**UPDATE**

Code to save all matches:

```
function Get-FormDataById ($path, $id){
  $dataRegex = "^$id(.+)$"
  $allMatches = @()
  Get-Content $path  | % { 
    if ($_ -match $dataRegex ) { 
       $allMatches += $matches[1]
    }
  }
  $allMatches
}
```

Lets change the content of `C:\test.txt` now to

```
name: John Smith
name: Jane Smith
age: 28
```

Usage

```
$allMatches = Get-FormDataById -path "C:\test.txt" -id "name: " 
$allMatches[0] //returns 'John Smith'
$allMatches[1] //returns 'Jane Smith'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! One last thing - is it possible to get the value of the second match? (i.e. there are two 'Name' strings in the file)

Comment: @Yad, I've updated my answer to explain how it is possible to get the value of the second match.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looking at it now - the code is actually really simple. Very helpful - thank you.